# How to create this horizontal menu with dropdown?

Tags: jquery, css

How to do something like this?

[pic http://img202.imageshack.us/img202/6295/menupmm.png](http://img202.imageshack.us/img202/6295/menupmm.png)

Any tutorial online?

Comment: 'Any tutorial online?' - http://tinyurl.com/3utt668

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nested `ul`'s.

The dropdown affect can be created with pure CSS by doing something like:

```
ul.toplevel li ul.secondlevel
{
   display:none;
}

ul.toplevel li:hover ul.secondlevel
{
   display:block;
}
```